# QGIS how to make unedited data?

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes

I have a table in QGIS (using QGIS 2.4). I have created a form for adding attributes. When I add new objects on the layer, I also create it's attributes. Can I make attributes that I have added non-editable for users?

Maybe I can do it if I add a PostgresQL layer and create some restrictions?

Comment: Please clarify: Do you want that nobody, except you, can add new features (geometry+attributes)? Should users be blocked from editing geometry+attributes or just attributes?

Comment: I want evrybody can add new features (geometry+attributes), but after they added only I can edit attributes.

Comment: Grant only SELECT and INSERT for your users http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html.